# Visual C++ or C play sounds

Tags: c, visual-c++, playsound

I'm developping an easy game written in C (Visual C++)
and I want to know if there is a way to play sounds,
thanks
(I'm using Visual Studio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [PlaySound()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743680.aspx) function.

If you call `PlaySound()` with the `SND_ASYNC` flag, the function returns immediately after beginning the sound.

For example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

PlaySound(L"test.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME);
```

You'll also have to add `Winmm.lib` in your project settings.

---

Here's a quick example that should work:

```
#pragma once

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    if(!PlaySound(L"test.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME))
        printf("error\n");
    else
        printf("ok\n");

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

and in stdafx.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <conio.h>
```

Comment: Where can I find the lib? And when i add the code it gives me loads of errors.

Comment: It's already available, you just have to add `Winmm.lib` to `Linker/Input/Additional Dependencies` in your Project Settings. The errors are probably from the linker - if not, let me know, I'll check it out further then.

Comment: Where can I find the lib? And when i add the code it gives me loads of errors. It looks like I have some files damaged, it says "dentifier "WORD" is undefined"

Comment: What type of project are you running? Console, MFC, .. ?

Comment: Win32 Console Apllication, by including mmsystem.h I add other external dependies in which there are some errors, and the errors starts when UINT or WORD or CHAR variable are declared

Comment: Ok, try to include <windows.h> first (see updated answer).

Comment: Thanks, we're about to solve the problem, all the libraries errors are gone, but "PlaySoundW(LPCWSTR,HMODULE,DWORD)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [9]' to 'LPCWSTR' 
"

Comment: Ah, sorry, try this: `L"test.wav"` - or the macro: `_T("test.wav")`

Comment: I added a quick example (tested). Of course make sure there is a test.wav in the current directory. (or try to remove the SND_ASYNC flag to test)

Comment: Thank you :) Really helpful