# New to C++ and would like to know how to play an audio file using VS code 2019

Tags: c++, audio, visual-c++

I've looked online for how to play a audio file on C++ and looked at videos but most of them say to change the 'linker' to winmm library. The problem I have is finding where to change the properties in VSCode 2019. Also, when I try to use `#Include` it would show an error. Example:

```
#Include "stdafx.h"
#Include <Windows.h>
#Include <playsoundapi.h>
int main()
{
    PlaySound(TEXT("C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sound\Blop.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    return 0;
}
```

My goal is to just play an audio file using C++ from VSCode.

> Error -: cannot open source file "stdafx.h"´ ´cannot open source file "Windows.h"´ ´#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sound\Audio.cpp).´ ´cannot open source file "playsoundapi.h"

Comment: `"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sound\Blop.wav"` should probably be `"C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Sound\\Blop.wav"`

Comment: Also, `#Include` should be `#include`

Comment: `cannot open source file "stdafx.h"`
`cannot open source file "Windows.h"`
`#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Sound\Audio.cpp).`
`cannot open source file "playsoundapi.h"`

Comment: This other question should help you out: [Visual C++ or C play sounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819725/visual-c-or-c-play-sounds). The reply (and comments) there also explain how to configure the project.

Comment: The problem is i'm unsure how to add `winmm.lib` to my project settings in VSCode. I've tried looking online but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is not `#Include`. It should be correct as `#include`

Answer (score 0):

I already was a problem seem like you. So, by my experience, I think "#Include "stdafx.h" is the problem, you can't use "stdafx.h" in VS 2019 (Microsoft Visual Studio Comunity 2019), "stdafx.h" work very well in VS 2017 (Microsoft Visual Studio Comunity 2017), but "stdafx.h" was replaced by #include "pch.h"in VS 2019, in other words, you should use #include "pch.h" and not "stdafx.h". And more, you have to include the winmm.lib in linker/imput/aditional dependencies, so if you follow this link you can see how to include winmm.lib (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9WeDQHi6sJs). So, to VS 2019 you can use this code below, I use this code in VS 2019 and it works very well for me. The song that you would like to play should have to stay in the right directory, the name of the file that stays my .cpp code is teste_0027 (C:\Users\Rodrigo\source\repos\teste_0027\Debug), the file has to stay in .wav format, and more, when you will create the c++ project in VS 2019 you should create the project as model "Aplicativo de Console CLR" in my language (Portuguese-Brazil), in your language it should sound like "Console App CLR"...

```html
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <MMSystem.h>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool played = PlaySound(TEXT("ALAN-WALKER-Faded-Different-World-feat-Julia.wav"), NULL, SND_SYNC);
    cout << " Sucess or not " << played << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```